# Nested for Loop on multiple lists

Tags: python, networking, ip-address

I'm building a script that takes a number of IP's from a user input. the output of this is 2 lists.

I now need to run every possible combination of the IP's in list A against the IP's in list B.
So if a user entered: list A: 10.1.1.1 and List B: 192.168.1.1, 192.168.1.2

So i'd expect this output:
10.1.1.1 192.168.1.1
10.1.1.1 192.168.1.2

I've tried a few things, nested for loops, itertools etc. I can't seem to get the output I'm after.

Please see my code below:

```
import ipaddress
#from itertools import combinations
local_traffic_list = []
# nget the number of subnets as input
l_subnets = int(input("Enter number of Local Encryption Domain Subnets: "))
# get the user to enter the subnets, line by line and append to list
print("NOTE: Enter subnet with mask, then press enter and repeat!")
for i in range(0,l_subnets):
    local_traffic_subnets = input("Whats the local encryption domain? ")
    local_traffic_list.append(local_traffic_subnets)

# ensure this is a valid IP and convert to wildcard and make list
for item in local_traffic_list:
    host_wc_acl = ipaddress.ip_network(item).with_hostmask.replace("/", " ").splitlines()
    print(host_wc_acl)

remote_traffic_list = []
r_subnets = int(input("Enter number of Remote Encryption Domain Subnets: "))
print("NOTE: Enter subnet with mask, then press enter and repeat!")
for x in range(0,r_subnets):
    remote_traffic_subnets = input("Whats the remote encryption domain? ")
    remote_traffic_list.append(remote_traffic_subnets)

# ensure this is a valid IP and convert to wildcard  and make list
for item in remote_traffic_list:
    dest_wc_acl = ipaddress.ip_network(item).with_hostmask.replace("/", " ").splitlines()
    print(dest_wc_acl)

#joing source and dest's together for every possible solution

for host in host_wc_acl:
    for dest in dest_wc_acl:
        print(host+ " " + dest)
```

Here's what happens when i run it:

```
Enter number of Local Encryption Domain Subnets: 1
NOTE: Enter subnet with mask, then press enter and repeat!
Whats the local encryption domain? 10.1.1.1
['10.1.1.1 0.0.0.0']
Enter number of Remote Encryption Domain Subnets: 2
NOTE: Enter subnet with mask, then press enter and repeat!
Whats the remote encryption domain? 192.168.1.1
Whats the remote encryption domain? 192.168.1.2
['192.168.1.1 0.0.0.0']
['192.168.1.2 0.0.0.0']
10.1.1.1 0.0.0.0 192.168.1.2 0.0.0.0
```

My issue seems to be the nested for loop.. as when i print the two lists i get the expected output.
So my output only presents the last entry rather than all of them - is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Do you want the 0.0.0.0 included?

Comment: Sorry yeah I was unclear.i want the output to be: 10.1.1.1 0.0.0.0 192.168.1.1 0.0.0.0 on each line for all the different options.

Answer (score 0):

You can try cartesian() module in from sklearn.utils.extmath import cartesian this takes an array of array as input and performs cross-product of those arrays.

try this:

```
from sklearn.utils.extmath import cartesian
cartesian((local_traffic_list,remote_traffic_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed your code slightly:

```
import ipaddress
import itertools

local_traffic_list = []
remote_traffic_list = []

# get the number of subnets as input
l_subnets = int(input("Enter number of Local Encryption Domain Subnets: "))

# get the user to enter the subnets, line by line and append to list
print("NOTE: Enter subnet with mask, then press enter and repeat!")
for i in range(0,l_subnets):
    local_traffic_list.append(input("Whats the local encryption domain? "))

# ensure this is a valid IP and convert to wildcard and make list
host_wc_acl = [ipaddress.ip_network(item).with_hostmask.replace("/", " ").splitlines() for item in local_traffic_list]

# get the number of subnets as input
r_subnets = int(input("Enter number of Remote Encryption Domain Subnets: "))


print("NOTE: Enter subnet with mask, then press enter and repeat!")
for x in range(0,r_subnets):
    remote_traffic_list.append(input("Whats the remote encryption domain? "))

# ensure this is a valid IP and convert to wildcard  and make list
dest_wc_acl=[ipaddress.ip_network(item).with_hostmask.replace("/", " ").splitlines() for item in remote_traffic_list]

#joing source and dest's together for every possible solution
combinations = [" ".join(["ip permit"] + list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(a))) for a in itertools.product(host_wc_acl, dest_wc_acl)]

print(combinations)
```

output:

```
['ip permit 10.1.1.1 0.0.0.0 192.168.1.1 0.0.0.0', 'ip permit 10.1.1.1 0.0.0.0 192.168.1.2 0.0.0.0']
```

Comment: That seems to work, how would I then return that as obviously i cant do a return(*ip)

Comment: @aarich88 In what form do you need it returned ? A list of lists ?

Comment: I'm trying to use it with a template i've made in Jinja. so for each line I've got from your output i need a line in Jinja, that looks like: "ip permit 10.1.1.1 0.0.0.0 192.168.1.1 0.0.0.0" and so on.

Comment: @aarich88 like this ? (see edited answer)

Comment: Yeah, i think i can make that work! Thanks! @joostblack

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.